# Wordpress PHP How to make theme show Static front page code

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read the documentation on Word Press. I've watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwecNcdAUaY) to create a word press theme, but I can't seem to get the content to display.

In my `index.php` file for my theme I have the following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div>
    <?php
    // TO SHOW THE PAGE CONTENTS
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <!--Because the_content() works only inside a WP Loop -->
            <?php the_content(); ?> <!-- Page Content -->
    <?php
    endwhile; //resetting the page loop
    wp_reset_query(); //resetting the page query
    ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have 2 additional pages. `header.php` and `footer.php`. Both of the content from these pages show, and I have checked their html (in developer tools) to make sure they display correctly.

I have created a page in my Word Press using `www.myurl.com\wp-admin`. I titled the page `Home Page` and it content:

```
<img src="http://url.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Innokin-Logo.jpg" alt="Innokin Logo" width="243" height="93" />
<img src="http://url.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Kingscrown.jpg" alt="Kingscrown" width="225" height="225" />
<img src="http://url.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Suicide-Bunny.jpg" alt="Suicide Bunny" width="194" height="259" />
<img src="http://url.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Kangertech.jpg" alt="Kangertech" width="128" height="128" />
```

The front page just needs to display those 4 images. Then in my Theme settings I set the "Static Front Page" to "A Static Page" and I set the page in the drop down to `Home Page`.

But when I load the website URL it looks like it goes into an infinite loop and then it shows a message: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/vapekuet/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 527`. `formatting.php` is not a PHP page that I created so I am assuming there is something wrong with my loop.

**Can anyone tell me how to display the current pages content using word press and PHP**. I don't need any information from any other pages to show, only the current content for the current page. IE: Home Page.

I have also checked that the `Home Page` is set in `Admin -> Settings -> Reading`

Comment: have you created page template for homepage?

Comment: What do you mean by page template for the home page? If I understand correctly in php you will need to specify where the content needs to be outputted ? I want to output it when it reads the index.php page

Comment: So header AND footer are showing but then in the content it shows the error?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working, you were right I needed to add it in the page.php aswel

Comment: You should checkout wordpress template hierarchy for more information on what template it decides to use. There is a nice graph.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as I mentioned in my question, I watched the youtube video, and in the video we created the `page.php` file. `Page.php` seems to be the actual page template in which the content needs to show. Thanks to `Bhumi Shah` for the answer and [Word Press Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). It worked once I copied the loop from `index.php` to `page.php`

Comment: FWIW, WordPress doesn't require **page.php**...but if you do include it, you need to include a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is ok. The error may be due to the execution time taken to get the images or internet connection. Hope it will be OK after some time.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you didnt't create a header.php file, but you have included the function get_header(), wich require that file.

You have two options: including the header on the index.php or creatinga hader.php file.

The header should look something like that:

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php
/*
* Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
*/
global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'shape' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: I have a header.php file, it also outputs the content from the header.php file. The problem was that the page template `page.php` file didn't have the correct loop.